# How to access a property of a selected item in a ListBox and paste it in TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, listbox

I want to display the Job Title in the TextBox when I click on a person in the ListBox.

[image]

---

So as you can see I have a `job title`, a `name` and a `skill set`

```
private void lstFree_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtJobTitle = lstFree.SelectedIndex.ToString();
}
```

This is the code I wrote that I would assume would give me the goal I wanted.

Whenever I click as you can see on the form, it's just blank.

I will be happy to supply you with more information pertaining to Constructors or anything on the like.

This is the code for the `Member` class that all the `Employees` run through.

```
public enum Job { Employee, Supervisor, Administrator };

public enum Skills {CSharp, SQL, PHP, Javascript, Web, Python, Oracle, CPlus, Perl };

abstract class Member
{
    protected Job job;
    protected String employeeName;
    protected Skills skills;
}
```

Code used to populate ListBox:

```
private List<Employee> employees;
employees = new List<Employee>();
Employee e1 = new Employee(Job.Employee, "Ron Jeremy", Skills.CSharp);
employees.Add(e1);
//method to display all employees on listbox
```

Comment: Images are useful in a post, but make sure the post is still clear without them. If you post images of code or error messages, copy and paste or type the actual code or message into the post directly.

Comment: I have added the code at the bottom, all this code is on the form - thought some images would be better suited to relieving headaches, rather than loads of small writing -

Comment: A good rule of thumb to use is, whenever it's code, write code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cast the `SelectedItem` property back to the class type you populated the `ListBox` with, and then access the property you want off of it (such as the employee's name).

```
txtJobTitle.Text = ((Employee)lstFree.SelectedItem).Name;
```

Comment: I placed this code in the `SelectedIndexChanged` on the GUI and it still won't place it in the textbox, I tried `employeeName.ToString();` as well, to no avail.

Comment: I included the breakpoint on the `SelectedIndexChanged` and I clicked on a person, nothing happened, I then moved the same code into the `GUI_Load` and it gave me an error: `NullReferenceException... Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Comment: That worked, interesting, I was 'closeish' a while back, I assumed I had to cast 'something' to the listbox but I wasn't sure what. I don't think I would have ever got the last bit, what did that actually do?